# How to configure dynamic aliased paths in Nx?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, nrwl-nx, nrwl

**Background:**

I am building an Angular dashboard where I import widgets (Angular modules and components) dynamically (without routing). I achieved this with the help from this great article https://netbasal.com/welcome-to-the-ivy-league-lazy-loading-components-in-angular-v9-e76f0ee2854a.

I am also using Nx and my each widget is a 'NX Angular library'.

**Issue:**

In my code I'd like to use the path alias set with Nx like like so:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LayoutService {

  loadWidget(name: string) {
    return import(
      /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
      /* webpackPrefetch: true */
      `@dashboard/widget-${name}`
    );
  }
}
```

But this will result in an error saying module `@dashboard` not found. However, if I use path in non dynamic way like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LayoutService {

  loadInfoWidget() {
    return import(
      /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
      /* webpackPrefetch: true */
      `@dashboard/widget-info`
    );
  }
}
```

Then it all works fine. I understand the issue is that Webpack doesn't pick up the dynamic paths? Is it possible to configure?

**Note:**

If I use relative paths without alias like so:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LayoutService {

  loadWidget(name: string) {
    return import(
      /* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */
      /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
      /* webpackPrefetch: true */
      `../../../../widgets/${name}-widget/src/lib/${name}-widget.component`
    );
  }
}
```

Then it works, but this is a little 'ugly' and not sure yet if it will be causing any other issues. Plus it gives the chunk filename of something like `info-widget-src-lib-info-widget-component.js` which is also even more 'ugly' than, say 'dashboard-widget-info.js`.

**Question:**

So, is it possible to configure dynamic aliased paths with NX, typescript and Angular, if so how? Or if you have any better approach tackling this, please share your ideas.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, did you find an answer to this? I have the exact same use case and am trying to find a workaround.